# minimum path from top left to bottom right cell, where we can traverse in north, south, east, west directions

Tags: dynamic-programming, depth-first-search, backtracking, breadth-first-search, minimization

How to find minimum path from top left to bottom right cell in a 2D-matrix with costs where we can traverse in north, south, east, west directions.

Comment: This seems to be a classical shortest path problem, where the cost is on the nodes instead of the edges. Are the costs constrained to be, say, nonnegative? Otherwise, the problem might not be well-defined since cycles of negative cost could occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cost values are constrained to be nonnegative, the problem can be solved by [Dijkstra's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) shortest path algorithm. Otherwise, the problem is not well-defined since cycles of negative length occur. To be more specific, the weight for an edge from cell `A` to `B` is set to be the weight of `A`; the weight of the terminal cell in the bottom right corner is included in every path.